# Conducting ring free-falling in a variable magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, power, electromagnetic-induction

Consider a free-falling conducting ring oriented horizontally to Earth's surface. It then enters a region with magnetic field $B = B_o(1+\lambda z)$ where $+z$ is the vertical direction upwards.

By Faraday's law, an emf $E = A\lambda B_o v$ will be induced ($A$ is the area of the loop and $v$ is its instantaneous velocity), which in turn will cause resistive heating. My understanding is that, by conservation of energy, the ring will brake and reach a constant velocity (wouldn't it?). The potential energy lost will be emitted as heat due to resistive heating.

But the dilemna here is, when the ring reaches a constant velocity, Newton's second law should hold, i.e, another force must oppose and cancel out gravitational force. I presumed it would be the magnetic force, but, applying dF = idlB, I find that the magnetic force is directed radially outwards of the ring. So the question is, which force is canceling out gravitational force and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your force argument is correct, and the ring does not reach a terminal velocity. It continues to free-fall as usual. So that raises another question: where are the ohmic losses coming from, if not the lost potential energy? This is actually due to the strain in the ring: the magnetic force acts radially on the ring, creating a stress in the ring's wire which produces a resulting strain. The energy stored via the strain is released through resistive dissipation.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually. Magnetic net force will act on the ring.

Magnetic lines of forces never terminate, but since we see that flux is increasing while we go down, magnetic field will not be vertical, but slightly slant over the edge of the ring.

If we consider this, net magnetic force acts in vertical direction.
$$F_z = \frac{-dU}{dz}$$
Where $U = -(M×B_z)$

This argument calculates force which comes out to be directly proportional to velocity of ring, thus terminal velocity is achieved

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Please don't post formulae as pictures or plain text, but use MathJax instead. MathJax is easy for people on all devices to read, and can show up clearer on different screen sizes and resolutions. I've edited it here as an example. Look at [this Math SE meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick tutorial. Also, note that markdown needs two newline characters for a paragraph break to appear in the output; I've fixed that up here too.